# Laravel 5.2.37 Authentication scaffolding not showing login or register

Tags: php, laravel

I need some advice, i have just installed a fresh 5.2.37 version of Laravel.

Straight after the installation i setup the DB details in the .env file and then ran

```
php artisan make:auth
```

and then

```
php artisan migrate
```

Everything worked fine with no errors at all, when i view the index page of my site, i see the new landing page, but every time i click login or register it just returns 404's

There doesnt seem to be any login or register routes created, this is my routes.php file

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

There is an AuthController.php in the auth directory, but there is also no mention of a login or register route.

Have i missed a step?

Any help would be great.

Peace!

Comment: `Route::auth();`
is a shortcut to add all auth routes so the routes exist, can you share the full error

Answer (score 1):

Run `php artisan route:list` command. You should see these routes:

`login                   | ...\AuthController@showLoginForm
login                   | ...\AuthController@login
logout                  | ...\AuthController@logout
password/email          | ...\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail
password/reset          | ...\PasswordController@reset
password/reset/{token?} | ...\PasswordController@showResetForm
register                | ...\AuthController@showRegistrationForm
register                | ...\AuthController@register`

If you see these commands, auth is work.

So, just go to `http://you.app/register` for example and you'll see registration form.

Answer (score 0):

By default you can not the see the routes in your `routes.php` file.

As it returns 404 page , can you please check , `site/index.php/register` ?
Once you run the command , you should have an automated view in your app root directory.

From the navigation menu , you should be able to see the buttons to login and register.

Also you can check your database whether the table was created or not.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out when installing the brand new Ubuntu Server box, i forgot to setup mod-rewrite.

I have just gone through and it all works perfect now.

Sorry for any inconvenience.

Peace!